# Is it possible to use break with ternary operator

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary

Is it possible use the break and continue words with ternary operator?

There is an example:

```
int variable = 0;
        
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    variable = (i % 2 == 0) ? break : variable;
    System.out.println(variable);
```

Comment: no, as these are not expressions. The compiler expects something that can be assigned to the variable, those two statements do not fit that requirement. Have you tried it?

Comment: The compiler returns error. "Syntax error on token 'break', invalid Expression".

Comment: What would be the value of `variable` after the statement is executed?

Comment: "What would be the value of variable after the statement is executed?" - If you are asking about the code in the question, there isn't an answer because it can't be executed.

Comment: @Mestedepsu the question was what the value of the variable would be after the line is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible use the break and continue words with ternary operator?

No.  It doesn't really make sense, and thus isn't supported.

**EDIT**

The following code has been added to the question:

```
int variable = 5
        
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    variable = (variable == 5) ? break : variable
    System.out.println(variable)
```

`variable = (variable == 5) ? break : variable` isn't valid, but it were, I think that could be simplified to this:

int variable = 5

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    if(variable == 5) { break; }
    System.out.println(variable)
```

The "else" condition in your proposed ternary operator would be assigning the variable its own value, which of course is a step you can skip.

Presumably your actual scenario is more sensible than the way that sample code is written.  You wouldn't want `i < 10` if your intent was to quit when you got to 5.

Comment: My code already like this. I just wanted shorten it.

Thanks.